# Not using forms and not doing a submit and yet page refreshes - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below does not use a form and does not do a submit and yet on click of a button the page is reloaded.  A reload should not occur based on everything I have read.  I don't understand why.  Can anyone help?

I also tried adding event function to the button (see updated source code) and have updated the source below.  It did now work

```
<SCRIPT>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('input[type=button]').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover');
    });

    // get the php vars into local vars
    var req_status = '<?=$req_status?>';
    var member_id  = '<?=$mbr_id?>';
    var group_id   = '<?=$grp_id?>';

    if (req_status == 'member-is-grp-ldr') {
        $("#ok").prop('value', 'Unsubscribe'); 
        $('#ok').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#ok').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    } else if (req_status == 'member-not-in-group') {
        $("#ok").prop('value', 'Resubscribe'); 
        $('#ok').prop('disabled',false);
    } else if (req_status == 'member-removed') {
        $("#ok").prop('value', 'Resubscribe'); 
        $('#ok').prop('disabled',false);
        $("#close").prop('value', 'Close');
    } else {
        $("#ok").prop('value', 'Unsubscribe'); 
        $('#ok').prop("disabled",false);
    }

   $('#ok').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#ok').val() == "Unsubscribe") {
            $.post('./ajax_group_unsubscribe.php', {function:'unsubscribe', member_id:member_id, group_id:group_id}, function(status) {
                if (status = 'true') {
                    $("#ok").prop('value', 'Resubscribe'); 
                    $('#ok').prop('disabled',false);
                    $('#ok').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $("#close").prop('value', 'Close'); 
                    document.getElementById('remark').innerHTML = "You have been removed from the group:";  
                };
            });
        } else if ($('#ok').val() == "Resubscribe") {
            $.post('./ajax_group_unsubscribe.php', {function:'subscribe', member_id:member_id, group_id:group_id }, function(status) {                  
                if (status = 'true') {
                    $("#ok").prop('value', 'Unsubscribe'); 
                    $('#ok').prop('disabled',false);
                    $('#ok').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $("#close").prop('value', 'Close');
                    document.getElementById('remark').innerHTML = "You have been added to the group:";      
                };
            });
        }
    });
});

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="header_wrapper">
            Group Unsubscribe Request
        </div>
        <div id="groups_bg">
            <?php
                if ($req_status == "member-in-group") {
                    echo "<p id='remark'>Confirm you no longer want to receive messages for the group:</p>";
                    echo "<p><em>" . $grp_name . "</em></p>";
                } else if ($req_status == "member-not-in-group") {
                    echo "<p id='remark'>You are not currently in the group:</p>";
                    echo "<p><em>" . $grp_name . "</em></p>";
                } else if ($req_status == "member-removed") {
                    echo "<p id='remark'>You will no longer receive messages for the group:</p>";
                    echo "<p><em>" . $grp_name . "</em></p>";   
                } else {
                    echo "<p id='remark'>You are the group leader and may not unsubscribe from the group:</p>";
                    echo "<p><em>" . $grp_name . "</em></p>";
                }
            ?>
            <br>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="button" id="ok" name="ok" class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' value="Unsubscribe">
            <input type="button" id="close"  name="close"  class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' value="Cancel" onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the ajax code:

```
/* get a database object */
$db = new DatabaseA();

/* get the member id and group id */
$function  = $_POST['function'];
$member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
$group_id  = $_POST['group_id'];

/* initialize the return status - booleans not returned */
$ret_status = 'false';

/* if the member id and group id were provided then */
if ( ! empty($member_id) && ! empty($group_id) ) {

    /* get organization id for the group */
    $group_info = get_group_info($db, $group_id, "org_id, group_name");
    $org_id = $group_info['org_id'];
    $grp_name = $group_info['group_name'];

    /* get the group leader */
    $grp_ldr_id = get_group_leader($db, $group_id);

    /* if the member is not the group leader then */
    if ($member_id <> $grp_ldr_id) {

        /* if the member is unsubscribing then */
        if ( $function = "Unsubscribe" && ! empty($org_id) ) {

            /* delete the member from the group */
            remove_member_from_group($db, $member_id, $group_id, $org_id);

            /* notify the group leader */
            send_member_email($db, $grp_ldr_id, "Group Member Update", "Member " . $mbrfirst_name . " " . $mbrlast_name . " has unsubscribed from your group: " . $grp_name);

            /* indicate the member was unsubscribed */
            $ret_status = 'true';

        /* else if the member is resubscribing then */
        } else if ($function = "Resubscribe" && ! empty($org_id) ) {

            /* add the member to the group */
            add_member_to_group($db, $member_id, $group_id, $org_id);

            /* notify the group leader */
            send_member_email($db, $grp_ldr_id, "Group Member Update", "Member " . $mbrfirst_name . " " . $mbrlast_name . " has resubscribed to your group: " . $grp_name);

            /* indicate the member was subscribed */
            $ret_status = 'true';
        }
    }
}

/* return to the caller */
return ($ret_status);
```

Comment: try removing the window.open...

Comment: took out the window.open and that did not correct it.  That should not have been the issue anyway since the close button causes the window.open command to close the window.

Comment: @Tim I have tested your code without `window.open` and it doesn't reload the page.

Comment: The only suspicious thing in your code is:
`<input type="button" id="close"  name="close"  class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' value="Cancel" onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">` The onclick says: Open a new window and close self.
I have an error message when I test it, but I don't know what your browser is.
Does it reload in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

You are using single `=` in your `else` statement and you have missing closing curly braces in your inner `if` statements.

```
$('#ok').on('click', function() { 
    if ($('#ok').value == "Unsubscribe") {
        $.post('./ajax_group_unsubscribe.php', {function:'unsubscribe', member_id:member_id, group_id:group_id}, function(status) {
            if (status = 'true') {
                $("#ok").prop('value', 'Resubscribe'); 
                $('#ok').prop('disabled',false);
                $('#ok').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                $("#close").prop('value', 'Close'); 
                document.getElementById('remark').innerHTML = "You have been removed from the group:";
            }             
        });
    } else if ($('#ok').value == "Resubscribe") {
        $.post('./ajax_group_unsubscribe.php', {function:'subscribe', member_id:member_id, group_id:group_id }, function(status) {                  
            if (status = 'true') {
                $("#ok").prop('value', 'Unsubscribe'); 
                $('#ok').prop('disabled',false);
                $('#ok').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                $("#close").prop('value', 'Close');
                document.getElementById('remark').innerHTML = "You have been added to the group:";
            }    
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I did correct that but that is not why the page reload are occurring.  Due the page reload the values passed in originally are wiped out.  I realize I could store the values in php vars and test on reload.  But want to know why the reloads are occurring.

Comment: @Tim you also forgot to close your `if` statements.

Comment: why do you think the if statements were not closed?  chrome debugger not showing any issues there.

Comment: @Tim it was showing on my machine, open the console tab and also compare my code and yours, it is clearly visible that the if statement are not closed.

Comment: Julekgwa, I apologize.   You were correct about the code I posted.  I had removed an else block to in order to shorten the code in the post.  I double checked the actual code and it was correct.  I am stymied by this issue, as nothing I have tried is stopping the reload.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `<input></input>` You should use `<button type="button"></button>`.
Clicking on an input is interpreted as submiting.

Comment: That did not correct the problem(still refreshed) and also broke the buttons (the labels were gone).

Comment: I did get all the button labels working properly but the page still reloads

Comment: Is that all your code that might cause the problem? It doesnt refresh my page. What is your ajax_group_unsubscribe.php code?

Comment: Good question regarding the ajax code.  It takes the values passed in by doing a $_POST and then updates the database and returns a status to the caller.  It does nothing with the UI.

Comment: took out the posts and the window does not refresh.  So why would the post be causing a refresh?